# C# How to find how much of numbers are Entered?

Tags: c#

How to find how much of numbers are Entered ?

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string x;               
        double t, s = 1;
        while ((x = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
        {        



        }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, please use the description to enter a description that explains the problem (in more than 9 words)

Comment: Do you want to convert `x` to a number and store it in `t`? Or verify that x is a valid number ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the number entered as a double, you would use double.TryParse [Google here](http://google.com/#q=c-sharp+double.tryparse) to convert "x" into "t" and then act on it somehow. If you want something more specific, you need to share what you're trying to do (expected input/expected output). Your English "how much of numbers are Entered" is not clear.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string x;               
    double t,tot=0, s = 1;
    while ((x = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
    {        
        if(double.TryParse(x,out t))
        {
            //t is now the number entered as a double -- process
            tot+= t;
            Console.WriteLine(s==1?"Please enter your second number":"The sum of your "+s.ToString()+" numbers is "+tot.ToString("N0"));
            s++;


        }else{

            Console.WriteLine("You may only enter numbers. Please try again.\n");

        }

    }
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. [link](http://pastebin.com/YL80B9Qz) . Its my code. For example i entered "5" "4" "3" numbers. The result is 60 . And in next line i need show how much numbers i entered for this example i need show "3"

Comment: OK - I just edited my answer to do what I think you are looking for. Is that what you wanted it to do?